# Writing Spark Sql Dataframe to disk as parquet/csv

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, etl, parquet

I'm reading a dataset as spark sql dataframe of shape(70000,38) using read.csv and then write to disk as parquet/csv using dataframe.write, It is not throwing any error, all fine!

When I read the dataset as spark sql dataframe of shape(70000,38), **do some ETL operations** and trying to write the spark sql dataframe of shape (80000,40) to disk as parquet/csv using dataframe.write, It is throwing error.

Could this be the reason? My resources got exhausted during ETL operations and unable to write the dataframe to disk.

My pyspark session configuration is

```
[('spark.rdd.compress', 'True'),
('spark.driver.port', '54782'),
('spark.app.id', 'local-1585668573104'),
('spark.serializer.objectStreamReset', '100'),
('spark.master', 'local[*]'),
('spark.submit.pyFiles', ''),
('spark.executor.id', 'driver'),
('spark.submit.deployMode', 'client'),
('spark.ui.showConsoleProgress', 'true'),
('spark.rpc.message.maxSize', '1024'),
('spark.app.name', 'pyspark-shell'),
('spark.driver.host', XXXXXXXXXXX.net')]
```

system configuration 8 cores/cpu's and 8gb memory/ram

will be grateful for any solution

**Py spark commands**

filepath = directory path of file to be saved

```
dataframe.write.format('csv').option("header", "true").save(filepath)
```

**Traceback of Error**

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o568.save.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:226)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:178)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:104)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:102)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:123)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:173)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:211)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:208)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:169)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:110)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:109)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.$anonfun$runCommand$1(DataFrameWriter.scala:828)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$4(SQLExecution.scala:100)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:160)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:828)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:309)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:293)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:236)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 2 in stage 6.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 2.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 235, IN2391797W1.ey.net, executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\spark\spark-3.0.0-preview2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 577, in main
File "C:\spark\spark-3.0.0-preview2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\serializers.py", line 835, in read_int
length = stream.read(4)
File "C:\Users\Sravan.Tallozu\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\socket.py", line 589, in readinto
return self._sock.recv_into(b)
socket.timeout: timed out

at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:484)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$2.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:81)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$2.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:64)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:437)
at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:489)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage6.processNext(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:726)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage8.agg_doAggregateWithKeys_0$(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage8.processNext(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:726)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:132)
at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:441)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:444)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1989)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:1977)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1976)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1976)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:956)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:956)
at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:956)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2206)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2155)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2144)
at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:758)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2116)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:195)
30 more
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\spark\spark-3.0.0-preview2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 577, in main
File "C:\spark\spark-3.0.0-preview2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\serializers.py", line 835, in read_int
length = stream.read(4)
File "C:\Users\Sravan.Tallozu\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\socket.py", line 589, in readinto
return self._sock.recv_into(b)
socket.timeout: timed out

at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:484)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$2.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:81)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$2.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:64)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:437)
at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:489)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage6.processNext(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:726)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage8.agg_doAggregateWithKeys_0$(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage8.processNext(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:726)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:132)
at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:441)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:444)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
1 more
```